# Spring Boot : IllegalStateException:Duplicate fragment name spring_web

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Facing **IllegalStateException:Duplicate fragment name spring_web** in spring boot application.
Went through few articles but everyone suggest solution related to **web.xml**. But in Spring Boot we don't have web.xml . What could be best possible solutions in Spring Boot.
For my organisation we need application to be build in war package. While executing in eclipse everything is fine. But when tried deploying in external tomcat 9 server we are facing this issue.

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath />
  <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>appname</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>appname</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- exclude tomcat jdbc connection pool, use HikariCP -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <!-- exclude tomcat-jdbc, Spring Boot will use HikariCP automatically -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
     <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- For MySQL -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.40</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
     <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
     <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
```

You have repeated this one, remove one of them.

You can allow duplicates by doing that

```
 <webAppConfig>
    ...
    <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
    ...
  </webAppConfig>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. But it didn't helped by changing both cases!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to you pom.xml:

```
<webAppConfig>
<allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
</webAppConfig>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. But it didn't helped by changing above configuration

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are looking for this thing but I am having the same thing, where I have a spring boot application and I am creating war from it.
I am keeping the web.xml file but don't have anything in it. This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>Basic</display-name>
    <description>Basic Application</description>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I am initialising the application from spring using this class.

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ApplicationWebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ApplicationSecurityConfig.class};
    }


}
```

I am able to run the application from Eclipse as well as deployed it in Tomcat.

I have not added spring boot tomcat dependency in the application.